# Is my iPhone 7 that was bought in Japan compatible with Verizon neywork and H2O wireless network?

Tags: iphone, network

I would like to know if my new phone, iPhone 7 (A1779) from Japan works on Verizon and H2O wireless network. According to the spec sheet of an iPhone 7 from Apple web page, the compatible cellular bands are:

```
FDD-LTE（band 1、2、3、4、5、7、8、11、12、13、17、18、19、20、21、25、26、27、28、29、30）
TD-LTE（band 38、39、40、41）
TD-SCDMA 1,900（F）、2,000（A）
CDMA EV-DO Rev. A（800、1,900、2,100MHz）
UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA（850、900、1,700/2,100、1,900、2,100MHz）
GSM/EDGE（850、900、1,800、1,900MHz）
```

but I don't know about this kinds of stuff so well, so I want to ask you if my Japanese iPhone 7 works or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes. The A1660 (which supports both GSM and CDMA) is identical in terms of cellular capabilities.](https://www.techwalls.com/iphone-7-plus-model-differences/) This is the phone you'd get under a Verizon contract, or if you just buy one without a contract. The A1779 differs only in that it includes contactless NFC for use in Japan.

All models of the iPhone 7 support GSM, so H20 is no problem.